# TFS Find matching Files with OR

Tags: tfs, build

So I want to find all the .xml and .pdb files and delete them from a build output folder.  I can do this one at a time, but can I do this as one find matching files.

Comment: Are you asking about doing it inside a MSBuild script?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you are doing this as part of the TFS build process template then you need a few activities and a variable. I'll do my best to talk you through it.

1. Create a **Sequence** somewhere after the build has completed - I put mine just after where the files were copied to the Drop Location.
2. Create a variable scoped to the **Sequence** called `matchedFiles` of type `IEnumerable<String>`
3. Add a **FindMatchingFiles** Activity to the Sequence and set the properties as follows

   - **MatchPattern**: `String.Format("{0}\**\*.xml;{0}\**\*.pdb", BuildDetail.DropLocation)` . You can change it to use `BinariesDirectory` if you are not cleaning the Drop Folder.
   - **Result**: `matchedFiles`
4. Add a **ForEach** Activity to the sequence and set the properties as follows:

   - **Type**: `String`.
   - Foreach `file` in `matchedFiles`
   - In the **Body** add a new **InvokeMethod** activity and set the properties as follows:

     - **TargetType**: `System.IO.File`
     - **MethodName**: `Delete`
     - **Parameter**: Direction: `In` Type: `String` Value: `file`

Now to avoid having a every File Delete in your build log, open the Process Template XAML with Visual Studio, find the `InvokeMethod` step, and add the following Attribute to the XAML:

```
mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="None"
```

Comment: +1 for the mtbwt:BuildTrackingParticipant.Importance="None" tip. Thanks.

Comment: @DaveShaw, Such a great answer.  If I could upvote it 100 times I would.  Thanks!

Comment: I wish I had found this 6 months ago. Thanks, DaveShaw!